# Play gif again afterclick javascript

Tags: javascript, gif

I have an image that gets replaced by a gif when clicked.
How to make it play again once every time the gif is shown?
That is, each display is one play.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("pic-div");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
    var y = document.getElementById("gif-div");
    if (y.style.display === "block") {
        y.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        y.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#pic-div {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
}

.gif-div {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction()">
  <div id="pic-div">
    <img
      src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/british-shorthair-front-white-wall_191971-17751.jpg?w=2000"
    />
  </div>

  <div id="gif-div">
    <img src="https://i.gifer.com/Z97X.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I am successful only in changing in Photoshop the GIF playing - once. but I don't know what to do in JS.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain it? If I click on the gif (that's automatically playing), the image will be shown. If I click on the image, the gif will be shown (and it's playing automatically).

Comment: I'll reformulate the question.

I have an image, which gets replaced by a gif when clicked. I don't want the gif to loop. Can I do this in VSCode, or is it possible only in Photoshop?

Because when I do this in Photoshop, the gif does play only once, but I can't make it play again when I click the image a second time.

So what I want is for the gif not to be looped, but be playable multiple times when the image is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, so to save you time, no, you can't control gifs through JavaScript. You either need to know the exact timing for the GIF and stop it once it reaches that, or a better option would be to change it to an MP4 and use it through `<video>` tag which is [actually a better practice](https://web.dev/replace-gifs-with-videos/).

Comment: You can use any hex editor and change [the two bytes starting at offset 31D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF) to zero to turn off looping.